# DB Dinamico MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

Estou iniciando um projeto web e estou pensando em usar java com mongoDB e Spring data. Nesse projeto web, cada usuário teria um banco próprio. Ou seja, quando o usuário fizer login (esse sim seria um banco compartilhado, onde conteria somente os dados de login), gostaria que usasse o banco de dados de determinado usuário. É possível isso? Qual seria a forma mais elegante de implementar ? Segui o exemplo desse [link](http://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-hello-world-example/), onde utiliza spring data com mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

O mongoDB é um banco de dados orientado a documentos, por tanto é NoSQL. Isso significa que **não** é necessário ter uma estrutura rígida para cada registro, você pode ajustá-lo/modificá-lo no formato que desejar.

O mongoDB organiza esses documento em coleções para facilitar as consultas e organização das informações.

**O que tudo isso significa?**

Na minha visão, você não precisa de vários bancos, mas de vários formatos de documentos (registros) diferentes - e você escolheu o banco certo para isso :)

**Exemplo**

Suponha que você tem uma tela de cliente diferentes para cada tipo de usuário (a tela é a mesma, mas as informações são diferentes). Como isso deve ser organizado:

Coleção: TelaDeCliente

```
// Documento para o cliente A:
{
 _id: 'UM OBJECTID PARA O CLIENTE A',
 owner: 'usuário2',
 nome: 'Cliente A',
 ultimoContato: '2014-01-01'
}

// Documento para o Cliente B:
{
 _id: 'UM OBJECTID PARA O CLIENTE B',
 owner: 'usuário1',
 razaoSocial: 'Cliente B ltda',
 totalVendas: 100,
 nomeContatoComercial: 'João'
}
```

Ambos os documento (json), estão na mesma coleção, porém, cada um tem um conjunto de informações diferentes; informações estas pertinentes a cada cliente. 
A única informação comum entre os documentos são os campos `_id` e `owner`, para que você consiga encontrar a informação que precisa.

**O grande truque**

Todos os documentos terão a informação `owner:'id do usuário dono'`. Esses campos servirão para você identificar que o `documento X pertence ao usuário Y`. Assim, você consegue manter um banco em um formato padrão (previsível), porém, com informações diferentes para cada usuário.

**Vários bancos de dados será ruim**

Se você instalar (criar um novo) banco de dados para cada usuário, você terá um sistema para cada usuário.

```
10 usuário = 10 sistemas diferentes
```

A manutenção para esse tipo de sistema e extremamente cara e dispendiosa. Evite esse tipo de comportamento quando construir sistema.

Answer (score 0):

Neste link que você passou, você teria que alterar esta classe para obter o resultado desejado:

```java
@Configuration
public class SpringMongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    public @Bean
    MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception 
    {
        // Ao invés de retornar uma Factory com "yourdb", retornaria uma factory por usuário
        // return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(), "yourdb");
    }

    public @Bean
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());

        return mongoTemplate;
    }
}
```

O problema da sua implementação é que teria que haver um *database* adicional para registrar seus usuários. O resto da implementação dependeria da tecnologia escolhida para este gerenciamento.